How to manipulate the first few digits of a Smart Contract?
I saw some devs that can pick the few digits of their choice for their smart contract, like 0xd0d0, and I saw that some even do more than 4 digits (like 5-6 digits after 0x). Does anyone know how to do it?

You can mine smart contract addresses by just generating a lot of them randomly and picking your favourite. You can also do the same for normal addresses.
This is called a profanity address. There has been security incidents around the practice in the past.

Thanks for the clarification, Mikko. Apologies for misunderstanding. I’ve deleted my answer.
